# Dojo tooltip not displaying in Internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dojo

I have this bit of code below to display the tooltip next to the text.

The code work fine as expected in firefox and chrome, but it doesnot work in IE 8 and IE9

```
var gridTooltip = new Tooltip({
                connectId: "grid1",
                selector: "td",
                position: ["above"],
                getContent: function(matchedNode){
                    var childNode = matchedNode.childNodes[0];
                    if(childNode.nodeType == 1 && childNode.className == "user") {
                        this.position = ["after"];
                        this.open(childNode);
                        return false;                
                    }
                    if(matchedNode.className && matchedNode.className == "user") {
                        this.position = ["after"];            
                    } else {
                        this.position = ["above"];                               
                    }

                    return matchedNode.textContent;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

textContent is not supported in IE I don't think...

Try changing:

```
return matchedNode.textContent;
```

to:

```
return matchedNode.textContent || matchedNode.innerText;
```

or use innerHTML.